# Data check routine isn't working

Tags: python

I have a file containing a 5 x 7 table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSWyl.png)
I want a validation check that there is either a 5,7, or 9; but none of them is repeated, i.e there must be only one occurrence of these numbers.  5 and 7 are required, 9 is optional, the remaining three columns can be 0. I have written this code but it doesn't work. I also want to store the valid rows in a separate list.
My attempt of the program in python is as follows

```
def validation ():
    numlist = open("scores.txt","r")
    invalidnum=0
    for line in numlist:
        x = line.count("0")
        inv1 = line.count("1")
        inv2 = line.count("2")
        inv3 = line.count("3")
        if x > 2 or inv1 > 1 or inv2 > 1 or inv3 > 1 or line not in ("0","5","7","9"):
        invalidnum=invalidnum+1
           print(invalidnum,"Invalid numbers found" 
        else:
            print("All numbers are valid in the list")
```

I will appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Comment: Please format your code. It's the only way we can see what you're actually doing - and relying on other people to do it for you is rude.

Comment: `line not in ("0","5", ...)` checks if the whole line neither equals "0" or "5" or ...

Comment: thanks paul it is kind of close to what I want but it gave me this ouput when I printed it [{'5', '0', '0\n', '9', '7'}, {'5', '0', '0\n', '9', '7'}, {'0\n', '0', '9', '7'}, {'0\n', '9', '7'}, {'0'}], I want all five elements of the row to get printed if it is valid here it prints,3,3,3,2,1 elements in the row

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  In particular, include the input, actual output, and desired output.

Comment: This is entirely unclear.  You state that three 0's is acceptable, but then your code issues an error for three.  You give 0, 5, 7, 9 as the only valid characters, but then your code counts and tests the quantity of 1, 2, and 3, but not 4, 6, and 8.  Also, you've made no apparent attempt to debug this -- put in `print` statements to see what's going on.  Finally, your posted code doesn't run at all, let alone giving output (syntax error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that uses a `set`:

```
lolwat = []
for line in open('scores.txt'):
    numbers = set(line.split(','))
    if '5' in numbers and '7' in numbers:
        print('okay 5,7')
    elif '9' in numbers:
        print('okay 9')
    lolwat.append(numbers)
do_stuff_with(lolwat)
```

Set de-duplicates the numbers ensuring each is unique like 5,7,9 only occur once.

Comment: But I actually don't only want the message. I also want the valid rows to be saved in a different list that i can then interpret for my calculations

Comment: @Paul https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @paul for example only the first two rows are valid and only those should be added and printed and not the other four. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to break a problem like that down into smaller pieces:

E.g., You want to check each row:

```
for row in open('scores.txt'):
    check_row(row)

def check_row(row):
    ...
```

You want to save good rows to a list:

```
good_rows = []
for row in ...:
    if check_row(row): good_rows.add(row)
```

A good row contains exactly one '5':

```
def check_row(row):
    number_of_fives = count_number_of(row, '5')
    if number_of_fives != 1:
        return False
    ...
    return True

def count_number_of(row, digit):
    ...
```

And so on.